# Styling react-rendered HTML by classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following HTML rendered by React:

```
<div class="m">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b e"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c e"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d e"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

I've been asked to set the DIVs to four specific colors based on the following rules:

- All `div.a` are to be colored green (easy enough);
- All `div.e` are to be colored orange (easy enough as well);
- If a set of 3 divs with classes `.b`, `.c` and `.d` respectively does not have an additional `.e` class attached, color them blue; and
- If any from a set of 3 divs with classes `.b`, `.c` and `.d` respectively does have an additional `.e` class attached, color the ones without the `.e` class red.

I know that I have absolutely NO access to jQuery on this system, so I'm after either a pure CSS solution to achieve this, or a means to implement these rules in Vanilla JavaScript within the constraints of React. One other caveat is that there are scenarios where this output may vary from execution to execution, but the `.e` will always be found alongside of a `.b`, `.c` or `.d` class. I also have no means of going back to changing the HTML once it is generated using `replace()` methods for example.

Is there a way to achieve the desired result set by the rules, given the current restrictions?

Comment: Yes it can ? but what do you mean by ---- If a set of 3 divs with classes .b, .c and .d

Comment: if there are these 3 divs one after another with these classes. one with b one with c and one with d. i dont know if he also means with the same order though

Comment: but why have b,c and d if the color doesnt change? why not have just b?

Comment: also post the code that generates this html please

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question this might be what you're looking for

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('m')[0].querySelectorAll('div');

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  //Check if in order b, c, d
  if(x[i].classList.contains('b') && (i + 2) < x.length 
      && x[i+1].classList.contains('c') 
      && x[i+2].classList.contains('d')) {
    //Check if any of the divs in order have the class e
    if(x[i].classList.contains('e') || x[i+1].classList.contains('e')
        || x[i+2].classList.contains('e')) {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      x[i+1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      x[i+2].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      x[i+1].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      x[i+2].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div.a { background-color: green;}
div.e { background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<div class="m">
  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
  <div class="c">3</div>
  <div class="d">4</div>
  <div class="a">5</div>
  <div class="b e">6</div>
  <div class="c">7</div>
  <div class="d">8</div>
  <div class="a">9</div>
  <div class="b">10</div>
  <div class="c e">11</div>
  <div class="d">12</div>
  <div class="a">13</div>
  <div class="b">14</div>
  <div class="c">15</div>
  <div class="d e">16</div>
  <div class="a">17</div>
  <div class="a">18</div>
  <div class="a">19</div>
  <div class="b">20</div>
  <div class="c">21</div>
</div>
```